# Imagemagick, how to remove a stamp and marks from an image?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, gimp

The scanned document image (grayscale) have two handwritten marks on the top and seal stamp at the bottom. I want to remove these marks and seal by replace them (hide) with same size rectangles, copied from another region of the image (part of background). How to do this with Imagemagick? Most important, how to get coordinates of these objects and rectangles? (areas where the background should be copied from).
IM v6.9 on Debian.

[image]

Comment: Overlaying is relatively straightforward but if you don't have the coordinates noone else is going to be able to give them to you

Comment: I determined the coordinates from the IM GUI: 104x77+930+23, 141x187+542+14, 120x71+414+336

Comment: Please add that to your question, which currently says you don't know this information. Make sure the question is an accurate representation of the problem you're trying to solve. Show what you've tried and explain how that didn't work. Make it easy to read and understand

Comment: Oh, sorry, the coordinates I gave is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter to us what the coordinates are. But if you don't put them in your question, your question remains saying that you don't know what they are, and that is unanswerable

Comment: Do you mean 1) you have a form which someone has completed and stamped and you want to take areas from the original, uncompleted form, to cover the stamp or 2) you want to take some other part of the same image to cover the stamps? The two are different.

Comment: I meant to copy a part of the background that is equal in size with target area and close in color, and paste it to the stamp area to cover(hide) it.

Comment: Ok, please provide a representative image along with the coordinates.

Comment: How to get these coordinates?

Comment: Mmm... your question implies you know where they are. If you don't know where they are, you need to [edit] your question and make that clear. And also provide proper representative images.

Comment: To get these coordinates is the most difficult part of the task.

Comment: Well, nobody will find unspecified objects on a white page...